# BeautifulSoup scraping investing.com ; AttributeError: issues with table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I spend like hours to solve a presumably easy task but couldn't figure it out: I tried to scrape data from the following site that contains a table.

However, I get an AttributeError if I try to extract the data from the table `containers.findAll('td')`

I searched several sites but it seems to work for everyone but me.. Anyone an idea?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

#OpenURL
url = requests.get('https://www.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc-balance-sheet',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

#DETERMINE FORMAT
content_page = soup(url.content,'html.parser')

containers = content_page.findAll('table', {'class':'genTbl reportTbl'})
containers.findAll('td')   ## This doesnt work for some reason.. 
                           ## also tried .find('td') &  ('tr') etc.
```

The data should then be extracted with a for loop, but anyway since the above doesn't work, I'm stuck here..

```
A=[]

for row in containers.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    states=row.findAll('th') #To store second column data
    if len(cells)==6: #Only extract table body not heading
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
```

or

```
data = []
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

Comment: "However, I get an AttributeError" - is there any information in the error? Can you show us it if there is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findAll` return a `list` you need to iterate through it with `for` loop statment:

```
containers = content_page.findAll('table', {'class':'genTbl reportTbl'})
for table in containers:
    for td in table.findAll('td'):
        print(td.text)
```

**Output**

```
# and many others td's

Unrealized Gain (Loss)
-139
-
-124
-95
Other Equity, Total
-2925
-841
-26
-450
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want the whole text of 'td' then use:
containers = content_page.findAll('table', {'class':'genTbl reportTbl'})

```
for i in cointainers:
    a= i.findAll('td')
    print(a)
```

and if u simply want the text of 'td' then use:

```
for i in containers:
    for td in i.findAll('td'):
        print(td.text)
```